# Algebraic geometry and algebraic topology used in string theory

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, mathematical-physics, book-recommendation, string-theory

I am looking for a **comprehensive book or notes in algebraic geometry and algebraic topology techniques used in string theory compactifications** covering topics like orientifolds, orbiolds, Calabi-Yau manifolds and toric geometry, divisors, resolution of singularities, fiber bundles etc.

If it contains explicit examples and exercises it would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the CMI book on Mirror Symmetry by Hori et al, available [here](http://www.claymath.org/library/monographs/cmim01c.pdf) ? In particular chapters 6 and 7 seem relevant.